# How to properly compile text contained html which is not comming from scope

Tags: angularjs, binding, controller, scope, angularjs-ng-init

The base scenario is:

In my main diw wrapper i have:

```
<div class="main" ng-init="Messages ='By my opinion you should visit <a href="http:\\www.google.com">Google search</a>.';">
```

and i want to bind it in a div which is inside the main div wrapper like:

```
<div id="innerDiv" >{{ Messages}}</div>
```

but it renders the `Messages` like a string instead of string containing href. I tried to do it like:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="forry"> </div>
```

and adding the `forry` in my controller like:

```
 $scope.$watch('Messages', function () {

                $scope.forry = $scope.Messages;
            });
```

when its loaded. Here it loads just an empty content.

Please suggest hpw to render this variable like a string containing html.

Comment: What version of angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive is no longer supported in angular 1.2.  Try `ng-bind-html` instead:

```
<div ng-bind-html="forry"> </div>
```

You also need to use the `$sce` service to trust the html:

```
$scope.forry = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.Messages);
```

Comment: and then i get explosion in the console: "Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context."

Comment: :* :* :* first knowing aboutthe SCE service thank you sooo much